# Angular nested route without reloading parent data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS with the ui-state router which I really like and works well, but I've got a query regarding the loading of data. In my routes.js file, I have the following routes defined

```
    .state("meetings.show", {
      url: "/{meetingId}",
      views: {
        "@default": {
          controller: "MeetingsCtrl",
          templateUrl: "/templates/meetings/show.html"
        }
      }
    })


      .state("meetings.show.conclude", {
        url: "/conclude",
        views: {
          "@default": {
            controller: "MeetingsCtrl",
            templateUrl: "/templates/meetings/conclude.html"
          }
        }
      })
```

In the meetings controller, when in the meetings.show state, it fetches a bunch of data, and this is great. What I want to now do, is show the conclude state but prevent the data being reloaded.

Is there any nice way of keeping the data there, it just seems very wasteful to reload the data if I'm just going to go back to the page and have to reload it yet again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to share the whole controller- not just the data- and change up the view.

One solution would be to have an abstract base state `meetings.show` and create two child states: `meetings.show.loading` and `meetings.show.conclude`.

With a structure like that, you can define the controller on the abstract base state and only set the templateUrl on the two child states (allowing them to inherit the parent controller).

I may have missed the point though. If i haven't addressed your use case, would you mind describing the behavior / appearance of `meetings.show` and `meetings.show.conclude` in more depth?

Comment: So if there is an abstract base controller, then that data doesn't get reloaded? If that's the case then my current structure has an abstract base controller for every other controller. I've tried building up a hierarchy so I have the default state which is the abstract parent of all other states.

Comment: that is correct: your data will not be reloaded. I'm afrain I still don't totally understand your use case - can you walk me through the workflow from a use case point of view rather than technical description?

Comment: OK So there's a side menu which controls the contents of the main view. Each main view is controlled by a different state. The section I'm having issues with is when viewing a meeting resource. As part of the meeting screen, there is a new view I wish to show that is directly related to this meeting, so when I show it I don't want it reloading the meeting data, as it may simply be hidden again and have the user return to the meeting screen which would in turn load the data again. If the abstract state can do this then that's perfect :)

Comment: take a look at this: http://plnkr.co/edit/nmYj6798VllaV8pCYrWX?p=preview -- is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: That's exactly it! That's absolutely perfect :D thanks so much

Comment: glad to help, and glad someone else can help me evangelize ui-router! take a look at my blog entry re. the ui state stuff too: http://txt.fliglio.com/2013/05/angularjs-state-management-with-ui-router/

Comment: Not a problem. It is far nicer than the standard router :) ah nice article. I shall take a full read through that later :)